# How set the image of a node to the left of the other info in Drupal?

Tags: php, css, drupal, drupal-7, themes

I created a content type for books with Drupal (Structure->Kind of contents) and added fields for name, description, year of publication, etc. The default layout with **CorporateClean** theme looks like this:

[image: current layout]

And I would like it to be like this :

[image: desired layout]

I tried to include the following lines in `style.css` in my theme directory:

```
#content img {
float:left;
margin-right: 15px;
}
```

And I get this result :

[image]

What is the best way to customize a Drupal content with fields ?

Does a dedicated module exist ?

I read about php files (in theme directory) to customize specifics contents. Do you have experience with that?

Comment: do you try with my answer? you got some advance ?

Comment: I do, but only the first line is on the picture's right, the others lines remains below the picture.

Comment: which lines? Edit the answer please and add some html code, this code works for me, tell me wich theme you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `style.css` add this lines at the end:

In the Corporated Clean theme this works:

```
#content img {
float:left;
margin-right: 15px;
}

#content .field {
float:left;
width: 70%;
}

#content div.field-type-image  {
width: auto;
}
```

In the Mayo theme this works:

```
#content img {
float:left;
margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: @JeanJouX you got some advance?